# How to read large sav files in R with Big Data packages

Tags: r, bigdata, h2o

I want to load a large dataset in .sav format. I used h2o package. I started a connection using h2o.init and after the h2o.importFile to load the data in .sav format:

```
> h2o.init(ip = "localhost",nthreads = -1,max_mem_size = "3g")

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpW0VBWa\file232c4ba961b9/h2o_user_started_from_r.out
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpW0VBWa\file232c7e0c26fc/h2o_user_started_from_r.err

java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: . Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         3 seconds 81 milliseconds 
    H2O cluster timezone:       America/Costa_Rica 
    H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC 
    H2O cluster version:        3.32.1.3 
    H2O cluster version age:    2 months and 17 days  
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_user_gqo645 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   3.00 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    8 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  8 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54321 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
    H2O API Extensions:         Amazon S3, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, TargetEncoder, Core V4 
    R Version:                  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18) 

> datos_1 = h2o.importFile(path   = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Data/data.sav")

ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 400 Unable to parse URI query (url = http://localhost:54321/3/ImportFiles?path=C%3A%2FUsers%2FUser%2FDesktop%2FDataFdata.sav&pattern=)

Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <html> <head> <meta http-equiv=
                     (right here) ------^
```

When I try to load the data, I get this error. I want to known how to fix it and how to import .sav files properly.